# Storing auth data on the client side

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage, client-side

I have an application which uses Backbone JS to render its views (among other things like models etc.).

Parts of my application should only be displayed to admin users, but the only way for Backbone templates to know this is for some JS variable/localStorage/Cookie to be set to indicate such.

The first worry here would, of course, be security. I am only really storing things like User.id, User.isAdmin etc. in here. Furthermore, since the only things limited to administrators would involve server-side involvement, changing `User.isAdmin = true` on the client side will just give them the interface options, but none of the power.

I know that using Cookies for this sort of thing is probably frowned upon, and with good reason, since Cookies are sent to and fro across all HTTP requests creating unnecessary overheads.

Therefore my question is, how best should I tell my client-side application about User authentication data. I am using jStorage (http://www.jstorage.info) for localStorage access, but it does not use SessionStorage. Would the latter be more appropriate than the former?

Answer (score 0):

Speaking generally,  you need roles and possibly privileges on the server.  This way, even if a nefarious user tweaks the client, user cannot actually access or modify restricted data, because if they try, they still havent modified the role on the server.  If you audit log access, you will know fairly quickly if a user tries something for which they don't have privileges.

The worst that can happen under a scheme like this is the user could see what the admin screens look like.  This still might be a breach, since they might see buttons that could inform them how the system works.

If you need to protect that, you could delay the loading of the templates for the "Admin Section" of your app until after a users role has been verified.  So all restricted sections are almost loaded as a separate app (or an actual separate app).  That way, even if the user tries to fool the client to load the admin section, when the request goes to the server you don't return the module, since the server will not show the user as having admin privileges.

Comment: I should have clarified in my question ("changing User.isAdmin = true on the client side will just give them the interface options, but none of the power") but I am already checking everything on the server side anyway. My question is more related to storage implementations e.g. localStorage or sessionStorage or Cookies.

Comment: you should never store sensitive data in the browser.

Comment: it's not really sensitive data (e.g. passwords), just some flags for the interface. It won't change what they are and are not allowed to do, just what the interface displays.